# Get value attribute from an li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list with li elements in it. When I click on that particular item in the list, I want to extract the value of that li item and use it. In the example below I would want to extract the value "9".

How can I do this in jQuery?

```
<li sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" value="9">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>
        Category 1
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Don't invent attributes, use data-value="9" and fetch it by $('li').data('value')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, there is no `value` attribute available on an `li` element, and adding non-standard attributes will mean that your page is invalid. Instead, use `data-*` attributes.

You can then hook to the `click` event of the `a` element and get that `data` attribute from its parent `li`, like this:

```js
$('li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).closest('li').data('value'); // = 9
  console.log(value);

  // do something with the value here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" data-value="9">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span> Category 1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-sequence="1" title="Category 2" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" data-value="10">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span> Category 2
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

`li` doesn't have value attribute. use data-value instead like below:

```
<li sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" data-value="9">
<a href="#">
<span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 1</a></li>
```

Then use:

```
$('li.liEllipsis').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
});
```

Comment: `.data('value')` is more suitable!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `value` on `<li>`. It is **not valid**! Instead you can use `data-value` or something like that. Use this way:

```
$("li").click(function () {
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("li").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" value="9">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 1</a></li>
```

Comment: You say not to use value on `li`, then your code uses it...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But it works! It is one of the worst solutions, which fixes the OP's question. Many a times, you won't have control on the HTML generated. Do you agree with me?

Answer (score 1):

Little late but this can be helpful to few.
li tag does not have value attribute sewn already, but still you can use `dataset` feature provided. For example:

```
<li sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" value="9">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>
        Category 1
    </a>
</li>
```

To extract li's value:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).dataset.value);
})
```

I have been using this in vanilla javascript, should work fine for jquery as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a click handler for li element and then get its attribute value. also `value` is not valid attribute for li elements. however HTML5 allows you to  use custom attribute that starts with `data-`. you can use value attribute like `data-value`.

```
<li sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" data-value="9">
 <a href="#">
     <span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 1</a>
</li>
```

and then get them using `.data()`:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('value'));
})
```

Comment: Yes this works but I am not supposed to change the html. Any other work around that you can suggest?